# Count how many empty list are in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to find out how many empty list are in a list of list.
I tried counting how many list are the length of 1 but in python it is giving me the length of `[]` is 0 but the length of `[3,[]]` is 2.  Is there a way that I could count how many empty list are in a list.

Example list

```
[[1,[2,3,4],['hello',[]],['weather',['hot','rainy','sunny','cold']]]]
```

so I want to count the hello list as either 1 or count how many empty list are in this total string, which is 1.

Comment: Just as shown in my example list. [ [content,[more content] , [content,[more content]  , [content,[more content]  ]

Comment: Your example list is a bit unclear: it's missing 2 `]`.

Comment: I **think** your example list is _supposed_ to be `[ [1, [2,3,4]], ['hello', []], ['weather', ['hot','rainy','sunny','cold']] ]`. Is that correct?

Comment: @JRazor as per OP's comment above, it's likely that PM 2Ring has it right. Which would mean that your edit conflicts with OP's intent.

Answer (score 7):

```
def count_empties(lst, is_outer_list=True):
    if lst == []:
        # the outer list does not counted if it's empty
        return 0 if is_outer_list else 1
    elif isinstance(lst, list):
        return sum(count_empties(item, False) for item in lst)
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
target_list = [[1, [2, 3, 4, [], [1, 2, []]], ['hello', []], ['weather', ['hot', 'rainy', 'sunny', 'cold']]],
               [[[[1, [], []]]]]]
target_list2 = []
target_list3 = [[[[]]]]


def count_empty_list(l):
    count = 0

    if l == []:
        return 1
    elif isinstance(l, list):
        for sub in l:
            count += count_empty_list(sub)
    else:
        return 0

    return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print count_empty_list(target_list)
    print count_empty_list(target_list2)
    print count_empty_list(target_list3)
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/ares/PyCharmProjects/comparefiles/TEMP.py
5
1
1
```

May not as elegant as the first answer.